# Reaction of ester and and sodium ethoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry

I tried using C2H5ONa as the base, and then removing the alpha hydrogen, so that I can carry out SNGP, but can't proceed after this
please help :)
[image]

Comment: What is SNGP? Please provide more detail for what you have tried.

Comment: Look [here](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0288) to find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the anion you created will attack the ester group of another molecule of diethyl succinate to initially give a beta-keto-ester. The reaction regenerates EtO- so this beta-keto-ester is deprotonated and reacts with an internal ester group in a classic [Dieckmann Condensation](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/dieckmann-condensation.shtm) to give initially 2,5-Dicarbethoxy-1,4-cyclohexanedione. The second step of hot aqueous acid hydrolyses the esters to acids which then decarboxylate giving cyclohexane-1,4-dione (product 1).

There is an [Organic Syntheses procedure](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0288) for this exact reaction from which I have borrowed the reaction scheme.

[image]